# Regex for multiline matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a format like this:

```
-Note1: Value is 02
-Note 2: Line 1
Line 2
```

When I do String replace with regex, i want it to group like this:

```
"Note1" "Value is 02"
"Note 2" "Line 1
Line 2" (the value for Note 2 spans 2 lines, which makes it "Line 1\nLine 2")
```

My current regex have this output:

```
"Note1" "Value is 02"
"Note 2" "Line 1" (and leave out Line 2)
```

Current regex:

```
/-(.*):(.*|\n*)/g
```

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind the desired output, so someone can help you write the regex to achieve that?

Comment: @ScottHunter I clarified in the post, the value for Note 2 should be: "Line 1\nLine 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JavaScript does not support the Singleline (`/s`) flag you need to get creative:

```
/^-(.*?):(.*(?:[\r\n]+[^-].*)*)/gm
```

- `/^-` - start with a dash
- `(.*?):` - capture everything which is not a colon into group 1
- `(.*` - start group 2 and capture everything
- `(?:[\r\n]+[^-].*)*` - if a newline is detected and the line does not start with a dash then capture the entire line into group 2; repeat zero or more times as needed
- `)` - close group 2
- `/gm` - global and multiline flags

https://regex101.com/r/3YW3Mg/1

Comment: I want the value for Note 2 to be : "Line 1\nLine 2" (2 lines), I am sorry for not clarifying that in the post! I am using Javascript

Comment: you're a lifesaver, i didn't even think about having a dash in the middle of the value

Comment: @catmandx Glad I could help. I added an explanation of the regex sections so that you can better understand my thought process.

Comment: thank you again for the detailed explaination, i've been struggling with it for two days.